# Execute a cmd after JAR export in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Does Eclipse provide executing some commands or batch calls when exporting to JAR, like Post-build-Event in Visual Studio? I want to create jni4net a jar proxy automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the [Ant plugin](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/eclipse/792-using-custom-ant-build-script-eclipse-projects.html).